# SQL query to create and update the colum in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql

For my homework, I am asked to write an SQL statement to do the following.

Add a new column in the `registration` table which is (`module_name  char (15)`), and update this column corresponding to each `module_id` for `200`.   `module name` is `digital diary`, for `201` is `year planner` , for `202` is `b’day remainder`

I can do this using two or more statements but is there any way this can be done in a single sql statement?

Comment: If it is urgent check the [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) syntax.

Comment: you will have to alter the registration table with new column and after the alter statement you can write three update statements for respective `module_id` best and simple solutions.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović I think CASE can help here but i have no clue how to use this, can you please give me a small example?

Comment: Why does this have to be done in the same Batch? The question does not specifically state one batch, and it would be correct to carry out the above actions using 2 statements, each in its own batch.

Comment: @user1373168: Why do you need such a thing? Why don't you create a look-up `module` table with module ids and module names?

Comment: Interesting question. I was thinking you could maybe do this using default constraints, but that would work only if you would update the table for one _module_id_ I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with DEFAULT:

```
CREATE TABLE registration(module_id INT);
INSERT INTO registration(module_id) VALUES (100),(200),(201),(202);
```

Altering:

```
ALTER TABLE registration
ADD COLUMN module_name char(15)
    DEFAULT (CASE module_id WHEN 200 THEN 'digital diary'
                            WHEN 201 THEN 'year planner'
                            WHEN 202 THEN 'b’day remainder'
            END);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=48d7b53f1fb5df3fed5a92c1ba1e2a07)**

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that in a single batch, you can use `EXEC` command to run sql statements, this way you can do that in two different batch and a single query:

```
EXEC('statement1')

EXEC('statement2')
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a stored procedure, and write whatever statements you need there.

Comment: This would not work (Unless you meant stored procedures). The stored procedure would not compile since the procedure would have a statement to update the column `module_name`, but at compile time this column does not exist, and a stored procedure cannot contain multiple batches.